# Unable to access cookie after page redirect

Tags: php, cookies

I am setting a cookie containing a vlue in this format and redirecting to another page via the PHP header function. Here's the code,

```
setcookie("myCookie", $cookieValue, time() + $cookieLife, "/"); // cookieLife is expiration time in sec
header("Location: $baseURL/index.php"); // $baseURL is "http://localhost/mysite"
```

The cookie is getting set within the browser. However, I am unable to access the cookie value in the redirected page, i.e., "index.php". I am trying to access the cookie value with a simple echo like this,

```
echo $_COOKIE['myCookie'];
```

However instead of the cookie value, I get the following notice,

```
Notice: Undefined index: myCookie in /path/to/my/site/index.php on line 1
```

I have set the cookie path to "/" after looking at other solutions but am still unable to solve this.

Any help much appreciated.

**EDIT** :
I am testing this on XAMPP server, and the "mysite" here is actually an alias for another location on my hard drive. Could this be causing this issue?

Comment: Is one of this files in directory / subdomain / other domain? Please also add code which you are using to get cookie.

Comment: How are you trying to access the cookie? Please show some code

Comment: I'm trying to access via this: "echo $_COOKIE['myCookie'];". Also, the index.php file is including another php page which contains the html page. I tried calling the cookie from the index page directly and also from the included page - both dont work.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your cookie gets removed or dissapears once you've left the previous page.

1. Check if `time() + $cookieLife` is the desired time you want the cookie to live. The [PHP setcookie function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) tells me that your `$cookieLife` is the time in  seconds that you want your cookie to live, so make sure that it's the value you want it to be.
2. Use an extension to check your current cookies (and alter them if you need to). This way you can check and make sure if the cookie is living as long as you want it to (you already mentioned seeing the cookie being set, but I will include this just in case + for future visitors).

FireFox Extension: [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/web-developer/)

Chrome Extension: [Cookies](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookies/iphcomljdfghbkdcfndaijbokpgddeno)

Comment: The cookieLife works correctly - it sets the cookies expiration time to 5 days, and I've already tested it. Also, as I mentioned earlier, the cookies are getting set in the browser, but my php pages are unable to access it.

Comment: @JTG What browser are you using? Check http://davidwalsh.name/php-cookies on the subject of getting cookie values. Might be that your index page doesn't have the "rights" for that cookie (otherwise all websites could access all your cookies). It sounds like a security issue.

Comment: I have set the path parameter in setcookie to "/". Now, since the URL of my index.php is "localhost/mysite/index.php", I am assuming that all pages within "localhost/" will be able to access this cookie. By this logic, I should be able to access this cookie from any page from within the "mysite" directory as well, since its inside localhost. Or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: @JTG What you've said seems correct, and the cookie should be available to the entire domain. All I can think of is that somehow the cookie becomes unset :/

Comment: This cookie is part of a combination of data used by a login script to verify if the current user is logged in - if it was unset, it would mean the user has logged out, and would be returned to the login page. This has not happened, so I can confirm that the cookie is very much set. Moreover, its visible in browser cookie data as well.